# Not able to extend the size of an LVM logical volume

Tags: rhel, lvm

During RedHat installation, I created one volume group with two logical volumes in it.

```
Volume Group Name = VolGroup00
LVMs              = LogVol00 and LogVol01
```

```
LogVol00 size = 48G
LogVol01 size = 81G
```

I have added extra 146GB hard drive. I added that drive as a physical volume and ran the command `pvs`:

```
  PV         VG         Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda3  VolGroup00 lvm2 a-   132.00G      0
  /dev/sdb5  VolGroup00 lvm2 a-   136.09G 136.09G
```

Now I'm trying to extend the size of `LogVol01` from 81GB to +200Gb using the command

```
lvextend /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01 -l 100%VG
```

But it is giving me this error:

```
[root@APP ~]# lvextend /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01 -l 100%VG
  Extending logical volume LogVol01 to 268.09 GB
  Insufficient free space: 5917 extents needed, but only 4355 available
```

How can I fix this and extend my volume?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`-l 100%VG` will try to extend the logical volume so that its total size is equal to the volume group's total size. This is not what you want - you already have another logical volume in that VG, which is taking space.

If you want the logical volume to use all the available free space in the volume group, the switch should be  `-l +100%FREE` (i.e. make the new volume size be its current size plus 100% of the free space in the volume group).

(Whether that's a good idea or not completely depends on how well you know how the storage demands on the two LVs will evolve over time, I guess.)

Comment: Damn I really forgot the FREE Switch. Im really out of my head. You saved my Day. Thanks